# How to get partition ranges in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, partitioning

I have a partitioned table in SQL Enterprise 2005. I need to query the PARTITION FUNCTION to find it's partition ranges. What SQL query will give me those values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this from the SQL profiler watching the management studio generate the script for creating the function

```
SELECT sprv.value AS [Value],
       sprv.boundary_id AS [ID]
FROM sys.partition_functions AS spf
     INNER JOIN sys.partition_range_values sprv 
        ON sprv.function_id=spf.function_id
WHERE (spf.name=N'fnPartitionLast30Days')
ORDER BY [ID] ASC
```

Comment: THis gives following O/p:Value ID
1 1
5 2

Comment: How to infer partition range from this ?